# What to change to place text in the centre of the screen

Tags: linux, terminal, c

The following program will clear the screen

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    fputs("\033[2J", stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

So, what should I modify/add in the above code to put a text string in the middle of screen?

Note: screen size is: rows=25, columns=80

Comment: Please note that programming questions generally belong on [so] (see our [faq]). [unix.se] is mainly for users and administrators, not programmers. Here, it's likely that we'll tell you what API to use (yup, curses); but help with this C API is within the domain of SO, not U&L.

Comment: @Gilles: Sorry, i thought question is specific to Linux only so this the best place to post.

Answer (score 2):

In order to put text in the centre of the screen, you need to know a = how wide the text you are printing is (in visible character-terms); b = how wide the screen is (in visible character terms); then print (b/2 - a/2) buffering space characters before the string.

This kind of logic, and other related bits, are all handled in the `curses` library.   I suggest you investigate using it.

Comment: rows=25, columns=80

Comment: Always?  Are your users never going to resize the terminal?

Comment: no liberty to resize the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough method that works for you, you will need to first retrieve terminal size, and calculate the position of the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

using namespace std;

void output_middle (const char *s, int term_cols)
{
    cout << string ( (term_cols - strlen(s)) >> 1, ' ') << s << endl;
}

int main ( int argc , char **argv ) 
{
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);

    output_middle ("some string", w.ws_col);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


static void print_middle(int rows, int cols)
{
    int vt = rows/2,
        ht = 0;

    char *message = "Please wait, Copying from network ...";

    ht = (cols - strlen(message))/2;

    fputs("\033[2J", stdout);

    printf("%c[%d;%df", 0x1B, ht, vt);

    printf("%s", message);

}

int main()
{
    print_middle(25, 80);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this work with all possible terminal types?

Comment: This puts the cursor at position (22,12), the question was about centering text. And although these particular will work on practically any existing terminal, ncurses is better because it has other useful features (such as knowing how to get the terminal size, computing the display width of a string and so on).

Comment: @jmtd: should work perfectly on every VT100 supported terminal.

Comment: @Gilles: pasted the wrong code. Updated the question and the solution also.